# Locking issue : needs some brainstorming suggestions

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have server service which releases the table database if a certain criterian is satisfied. It looks like this

```
public static void autoUnloadDbTable(final Configuration conf) {
   final String mKey = getMapKey(conf);
   final Table table = TABLES.get(mKey);
   if (table != null) {
      dblock.getLock().lock();
      table.instance.dispose();
      TABLES.remove(mKey);.....(2)
   }
   //here release lock when done...
}
```

But there is another operation which can run sideways when the above function is being executed

```
public Table getTableLocked(final Lock lock) throws FactFinderException {
   boolean loadTable = true;
   // Get the current table instance
   Table table = TABLES.get(mapKey);
   // .....(1)
   if (table != null) {
      //do something
   }

   if (loadTable) table = loadTableLocked(table);

   // lock the table, so the instance don't gets replaced
   if (lock != null) lock.lock();   
   return table.instance;
}
```

At (1) i need to put something because if one thread is executing the code at (2) and the other thread is at thread (2) which already have a table object but as (2) is executing so it will delete the table object and then everything beyond (1) will not have a correct value....any suggestions please...??

Comment: After you return a table.instance, can autoUnloadDbTable still be called, and hence table.instance.dispose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a read/write lock around TABLES.  Acquire a read lock before you do TABLES.get(...) to use something from tables , and acquire a write lock before you do TABLES.get(...) to delete from it.

The alternative is to have a lock per table.  After a TABLES.get(...) acquire the Table specific lock, then make sure the Table is still in TABLES, then perform your action with the lock.  This Table specific lock can be a read/write lock as well, then only the code wishing to delete will acquire a write lock.  This gets complicated when you try to add to TABLES, you will need to be clever, and probably use a ConcurrentMap for TABLES, and use putIfAbsent.

Comment: TABLE = Collections.synchronizedMap so it already schyncronised so if i do something what you said i will lower the effeciency....Second ones also dosen't seem convencing...

Comment: first one is better, yes.  I doubt you will notice the loss of efficiency, locking in java is very fast.  As well, if you lock with a read/write lock you can make TABLES a normal map.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you could consider wrapping your tables:

```
public class LockableTable {
 public Table table;
 public ReadWriteLock lock;
 public LockableTable(Table t){
   table = t;
   lock = ....
 }
}
```

Then when you want to delete the table you take the `myLocakbleTable.lock.writeLock().lock()`. Rest of the time when you are reading from the table you take the `myLockableTable.lock.readLock().lock()`

Comment: No I can't see another lock and in addition the TABLES is a Collections.synchronizedMap . So I need to put something after (2) because putting before Table table = TABLES.get(mapKey) in (2) will degrade the effeciency...

Comment: Even If i use a readlock() at (2) and writelock at (2) it will not solve because what if in getTableLocked() function one thread is executed the  Table table = TABLES.get(mapKey); and then write lock at (2) sees ohh there is no read lock so grabs one writelock at (2) and then change the TABLES map and release lock...the (1) sees that no write lock grab a lock but then table instance is no more there as it is changed by write lock..i hope you got what i am trying to explain..:))

Comment: What @sbridges said. Before tableGet you use the ReadLock

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a ConcurrentHashMap, it is more efficient.

I think you can utilize ConcurrentHashMap's lock mechanism and remove your own.  So
remove first in section 1:

```
public static void autoUnloadDbTable(final Configuration conf) {
    final String mKey = getMapKey(conf);
    final Table table = TABLES.remove(mKey);
    if (table != null) {
      table.instance.dispose();
    }
}
```

Section 2 is like this:

```
public Table getTableLocked(final Lock lock) throws FactFinderException {
    boolean loadTable = true;
    // Get the current table instance
    Table table = TABLES.get(mapKey);
                // .....(1)
    if (table != null) {
                   //do something
    }

    if (loadTable) table = loadTableLocked(table);
    return table.instance;
}
```

}

Comment: ok use a synchronized map.  the code looks the same.  i'm not sure why you need to manage a separate lock.  remove and get are thread safe.

Comment: I don't think that works, as you can have one thread using a table after another thread has called dispose() on it.

Comment: It seems unavoidable since the table instance is being returned.  The caller has access to the instance at any time another thread can dispose it.  It seems that the table object needs to manage itself, to keep this safe.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?  If a user is using table.instance then it shouldn't be disposable.  Is that correct?